Chromatic numbers realised by almost disjoint subsets of $\omega$
If $H=(V,E)$ is a hypergraph then the chromatic number $\chi(H)$ is defined to be the least cardinal $\kappa \leq |V|$ such that there is a map $c:V\to \kappa$ such that for all $e\in E$ with $|e| \geq 2$ the restriction $c\restriction_e: e\to \kappa$ is not constant.
We say that $A, B\subseteq \omega$ are almost disjoint if $|A\cap B|$ is finite.
Given $n\in (\omega\setminus\{0,1\})\cup \{\omega\}$ is there a collection ${\cal A}\subseteq {\cal P}(\omega)$ of pairwise almost disjoint infinite sets such that $\chi(\omega, {\cal A}) = n$?

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but isn't this already true for graphs (which are hypergraphs with pairwise almost disjoint sets).

This question was answered affirmatively by Theorem 1.1 of Paul Erdős and Saharon Shelah, Separability properties of almost-disjoint families of sets, Israel J. Math. 12 (1972) 207–214 (pdf), improving earlier results of S. Hechler, Classifying almost-disjoint families with applications to $\beta N\setminus N$, Israel J. Math. 10 (1971) 413–432.
